# accordion h3 text disappears in IE

Tags: html, jquery-ui, css, accordion

Please check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fTmxc/3/) in IE. The menu item name is not visible in IE. It is working perfect in all other browsers.

Any idea??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were looking for rotation=3

http://jsfiddle.net/fTmxc/11/

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ff999999, endColorstr=#ffcccccc);  
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)"
            "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ff999999, endColorstr=#ffcccccc)";
```

Comment: You forgot to add `3` in the above link - Link Updated

Comment: Thanks and Y is the rounded corner for h3 tag is missing in IE?? Also there is some top padding also only in IE. It is not exactly like how it is working in all other browsers. Can u please chk that too

Comment: Rounded corners do not play well with filters. You get one or the other.

Comment: Mythril is right. You can only get them both if you give the `h3` a child that has the size of the `h3`, set the `filter` gradient on that child and the rounded corners plus `overflow: hidden` on the `h3`

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using CSS3 transform to rotate the text.

IE 6,7,8 does not support it. 
to make it work in ie9 you need to add following code

```
-ms-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
```

you can check this website to make it work in older browsers
http://www.aquim.com/web-article-226.html